# How to read double values from CSV file and add them to the same column in pandas?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, csv

The following data is in a CSV file:

```
SBUX, Starbucks,
YHOO, Yahoo,
ABK, Ambac Financial,
V, Visa,
MA, Mastercard,
MCD, McDonald's,
MCK, McKesson,
MDT, Metronic,
MRK, Merk&Co,
MAR, Marriott International,
MKTX, MarketAxess,
LRCX, LAM Research,
LOW, Lowe's
```

I want to add each row of the csv file to the same column in a pandas dataframe. I want the output to be the following:

Dataframe:

```
SBUX     |YHOO |ABK             |V   |MA        |MCD       |MCK     |MDT     |
Starbucks|Yahoo|Amback Financial|Visa|Mastercard|McDonald's|McKesson|Metronic|
```

How can I do that with Python?

Comment: `df = pd.read_csv("f.csv", skipinitialspace=True, index_col=[0]).iloc[:, :-1].T`.

Answer (score -1):

You can achieve this by reading the CSV file into a pandas DataFrame and then transposing it to set the first row as column headers and the second row as the data. Here's an example:

```
import pandas as pd

# Assuming 'data.csv' contains the provided CSV data
# Read the CSV file
data = pd.read_csv('data.csv', header=None)

# Transpose the DataFrame and set the first row as column headers
data_transposed = data.T

# Set the first row as column headers and drop the original header row
data_transposed.columns = data_transposed.iloc[0]
data_transposed = data_transposed.drop(0)

# Display the transposed DataFrame
print(data_transposed)
```

This code will read the CSV file, transpose the data, set the first row as column headers, and create the DataFrame as you described.

Keep in mind that if the CSV file has more rows or columns, this code will handle only the first two rows (header and corresponding data). Adjustments may be necessary if the CSV file contains additional information.